# redirect uri for browser based app

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, client-side, redirect, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I make a browser based app, which is entirely client-side, so I don't have to have any url, but only xml files (`manifest.xml`, `extractor.xml` and `gadget.xml` in my case) and deploy the application through Google Apps Engine (GAE). What and how should I supply in the `redirect uri` address?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not redirecting the user, I assume you're using the Google Javascript API client to authenticate them ?

If that's the case there is no redirect uri, it is an origin. And you must supply your App Engine app's domain (http://something.appspot.com or https://something.appspot.com) as the origin.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know I mistook...  
I intended `Google Apps` in [https://code.google.com/googleapps/console](https://code.google.com/googleapps/console). What is the difference between the `Google Apps` and the `Google Apps Engine`?

Comment: I try for several weeks to deploy a `gmail contextual gadget`, but I can't continue since I need `OAuth2.0` for the project and `deploy application` button in the `Google Apps` doesn't work. I don't know how to deploy the application unless I define OAuth2.0 for it, but I need a `redirect_uri` parameter to be filled, and I don't know which value it's requires. My files are only the 3 xmls I wrote in the question, and the javascript is generated by gmail after deploying when gmail page is loaded.